# Vue 3: I can't scroll down or up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

When I try to load a user's ( link schema example : test.com/!#/user/4qsdqsd7qdsqd ) page from a modal, I get the page but I can't scroll down or up. I have no errors in the logs. I also modified the history mode in HTML5 Mode that didn't change the bug. However, if I refresh the page with the refresh button of my browser. The page becomes normal and I can scroll
This is a **vuejs** application **(version 3)**

Router: next-router

```
{
path: "/",
redirect: "/dashboard",
component: DashboardLayout,
children: [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "dashboard",
    components: { default: Dashboard },
  },
  {
    path: "/user/:id",
    name: "profile",
    components: { default: Profile },
  },
  {
    path: "/reports",
    name: "Signalisations",
    components: { default: Reports },
  },
  {
    path: "/users",
    name: "Utilisateurs",
    components: { default: Users },
  },
  {
    path: "/addfeed",
    name: "Ajouter une publication",
    components: { default: AddFeed },
  },
],},
```

Here is where I declared the route for a user's page.

```
<modal v-model:show="modals.feedDetailsViewer">
<template v-slot:header>
  <h6 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-default">Détails</h6>
</template>
<div class="row">
  <div v-if="detailsViewerData.image_url !== ''" class="col-12">
    <h4>Photo</h4>
    <img
      :src="detailsViewerData.image_url"
      alt="image"
      style="width: 100%"
    />
  </div>
  <div v-if="detailsViewerData.video_url !== ''" class="col-12">
    <h4>Vidéo</h4>
    <video
      :src="detailsViewerData.video_url"
      alt="video"
      style="width: 100%"
    ></video>
  </div>
  <hr class="mt-4" />
  <div v-if="detailsViewerData.userPseudo !== ''" class="col-12">
    <h5 class="mt-3">Créer par</h5>
    <p>
      <!-- here link to user page  -->
      <router-link :to="'/user/' + detailsViewerData.userId">
        {{ detailsViewerData.userPseudo }}
      </router-link>
      <!-- end -->
    </p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="detailsViewerData.content != ''" class="col-12">
    <h5 class="mt-3">Contenu</h5>
    <p>{{ detailsViewerData.content }}</p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="detailsViewerData.nbrComments !== ''" class="col-12">
    <p>
      Commentaires: {{ detailsViewerData.nbrComments }}; Favoris:
      {{ detailsViewerData.favoriteCount }}; Partages:
      {{ detailsViewerData.repostCounts }};
    </p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="detailsViewerData.createdAt !== null" class="col-12">
    <h5 class="mt-3">Date de création</h5>
    <p>{{ getGoodDate(detailsViewerData.createdAt) }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<template v-slot:footer>
  <base-button
    type="link"
    class="ml-auto"
    @click="modals.feedDetailsViewer = false"
    >Fermer
  </base-button>
</template>
</modal>
```

here is the modal that contains the link of a user page

If someone knows what can cause this kind of bug, his help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: The example link is broken (404 error).

Comment: no it's just example not a real link

Comment: I think maybe you should show the code which renders the page too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router-view key was not updated automatically. After adding it the component of the user page is updated automatically

```
<router-view :key="$route.path" />
```